variable might not have been initialized in java (in if-statement)?
Code snippet 1
        double price = 90000;
        String model;
        if(price > 100000) {
            model = "Tesla Model X";
        } else if(price <= 100000) {
            model = "Tesla Model S";
        }
        System.out.println(model);

Code snippet 2
        double price = 90000;
        String model;
        if(price > 100000) {
            model = "Tesla Model X";
        } else{
            model = "Tesla Model S";
        }
        System.out.println(model);

I know, java has the rule to initialize local variables before accessing or using them. this is checked at compile time. Why the code snippet 2 works?, the compiler complain about code snippet 1: variable model might not have been initialized - I understand this
In code snippet 1,  I thought I've covered all possible cases for the price, so the model variable should always be initialized like the code snippet 2. Why is the compiler still complaining?
Can someone explain why the compiler thinks model might not be initialized?

NaN will ruin your day.

"In code snippet 1, I thought I've covered all possible cases for the price, so the model variable should always be initialized" - You can infer this information; the compiler - without loss of generality - can not.

Whether the code will compile will be dependent on whether the local variable has been assigned a value as per the rules of "definite assignment" as per the JLS section 16.

String model = price > 100000 ? "Tesla Model X" : "Tesla Model S";

@Elliott Frisch, this statement is equivalent to code snippet 2

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels, can you help me, which part should I read in that link, it is too long :(

Try making price final. I haven't tested this, but in extreme corner cases (e.g this was part of a convoluted threaded environment) the value of price could change between the two comparisons. In the second case, price is only compared once, the else is unaffected by any further change.

"You can infer this information; the compiler - without loss of generality - can not." - Indeed, it is not permitted to!  (If it didn't give a compilation error, that would make the compiler non-compliant with the Java Language Specification.)

Reading "16.2.7. if Statements" should cover it ... if you have read enough of the early part of Chapter 16 to understand the terminology.  But it is kinda moot.  The JLS says what it says, whether you read it / understood it or not :-)

@Stephen C, it's too hard to understand, what you said :(

My first comment is saying that the Java compiler is not permitted to be smart ... and work out that the price > 100000 and price <= 100000 covers all possible cases.  (I don't think it covers all cases anyway because of the weird semantics of NaN values.)

My second comment is trying to tell you what subsection of the JLS specifically covers if and if ... else statements.  But as I was trying to say, you don't need to understand the technical details of the JLS.  Just believe people (like me and HoverCraft and Elliot and Turing85) who do understand it.
